# Whether Outlook SDK be able to access Office365 User data? Or Microsoft Graph API be able to access Live.com users?

Tags: outlook, office365, office365-apps, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-api

Whether OutlookSDK at dev.outlook.com could access Office365 user data (calendars, contacts, mail)?

How's about Microsoft Graph API, could them be able access live.com users? (calendars, contacts, tasks, mail)?

I'm curious at this point, want to know what SDK is best for accessing both live.com user data and Office365 user data.

I already try Microsoft Graph API iOS SDK to authenticate Live Id user, but couldn't success, only able to authenticate Office365 user

OutlookSDK as well, unable to authenticate Office365 user, only able to authenticate Live ID

Thanks.

Comment: I used Outlook-SDK-Android (https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/android) but now is broken after Microsoft Authentication Protocols change (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-preview-oidc-changes/)..

Answer (score 2):

Carefully take a look at the instructions here: https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Overview

To write an app against both Office 365 and outlook.com you will need to register your application in the new application registration portal here: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/Disambiguation?ru=https%3a%2f%2fapps.dev.microsoft.com%2f

Additionally you will need to make sure that your Outlook.com account has been upgraded to the new service.  If it has not, then you will need to follow the instructions to request an account in the preview service from: outlookdev@microsoft.com or create a new account which should automatically be provisioned in the new service.

Comment: Hi, We switched to use OutlookSDK in this repository "https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-SDK-iOS" but how could we get working clientId, redirectUri, resouceId? I try with Application Registration Tool with both an Office 365 account and an Development Outlook Account  to register applications. but coudn't success. I get the error after authentication: Application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' is not supported for this API version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - You can use Outlook APIs to access mail, calendars, and contacts for Office 365 users and Outlook.com

Also, You can use the Microsoft Graph API to access fixed entities like users, groups, mail, messages, calendars, tasks, and notes coming from services like Outlook, OneDrive, Azure Active Directory, Planner, OneNote and others.

I suggest using O365 APIs to do Live id user authentication - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/

Check this link as well: http://dev.office.com/getting-started/office365apis

Comment: We switched to use OutlookSDK in this repository "https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-SDK-iOS" but how could we get working clientId, redirectUri, resouceId? I try with Application Registration Tool with both an Office 365 account and an Development Outlook Account  to register applications. but coudn't success. I get the error after authentication: Application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' is not supported for this API version.